# How to slide down text in container

Tags: jquery, css

Sorry if this is a bit of a silly question. I'm new with jQuery.

I'm trying to create a team members section where you click a team member, and then the information about that person slides down underneath.

I set it up so that the parent container detects the height of the team member's information, and animates in height dynamically for each person. This pushes the other team members down the appropriate amount so as to not be covered up.

My issue is that the information about the person just sort of appears... it doesnt animate down like the people do. I tried animating the ".team-content-container" down with a starting height of zero, but it didnt work correctly.

How can I get the whole section to smoothly animate down into view?

Any help?

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/Finches/pen/jYKmEd

```
// Show/hide content from clicking box title
$('.open-team-box').click(function() {

  //Get height of content
  var height = $(this).siblings('.team-content-container').height() + 350;

  //Convert height to string
  var heightStr = height.toString();

  //Toggle height and content box display
  if ($(this).parent('.team-container').height() == 350) {
      $(this).parent('.team-container').animate({height: heightStr});
      $(this).siblings('.team-content-container').show();
    console.log(height);
    }
  else if ($(this).parent('.team-container').height() == height) {
      console.log('test');
      $(this).siblings('.team-content-container').hide();
      $(this).parent('.team-container').animate({height: "350px"});
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried adding a timing to the `show()` and `hide()` functions: ex: `show('slow')`

Comment: Hi, I did... It sort of just grows from the left when I did that. I'm looking for more of a "whole container slides down into view together" kind of thing.

Comment: Off-topic: The toString() stuff doesn't seem to be necessary. I've never needed it.

Comment: Another tip: It's really not ideal to have your functionality depend on specific height values like that. Ideally you'd be able to modify your CSS without having to update the JS. Better to use CSS class toggling, etc.

Comment: What about [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) then? You have the terms in your question's title... You didn't ask Google, right?

Answer (score 0):

I guess to use an initToggle() function :

```
function initToggle(){
  $('.team-content-container').hide();
  $('.team-container').animate({height: "350px"});
}

 $('.open-team-box').click(function() {
    initToggle();
      //Get height of content
      var height = $(this).siblings('.team-content-container').height() + 350;

      //Convert height to string
      var heightStr = height.toString();

      //Toggle height and content box display
      if ($(this).parent('.team-container').height() == 350) {
          $(this).parent('.team-container').animate({height: heightStr});
          $(this).siblings('.team-content-container').show();
        console.log(height);
        }
    })
```

;